# redirect old url to new url with django

Tags: django, url, nginx, redirect, seo

I changed my website url to new one , but google is showing my old url , i have read that i need to make 301 redirect to help google to show my new url, but i don't know how to make it with django!

my old url :

```
path('<int:pk>/', views.ArticleDetail.as_view(), name='detail')
```

my new url :

```
path('<int:pk>/<slug>', views.ArticleDetail.as_view(), name='detail')
```

more info :
i'm using nginx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things you need to do to make sure that your website gets crawled properly.

In regards to the redirection, you can use `django.http.HttpResponsePermanentRedirect` to perform the redirection. Just keep the view, and when a user navigates to this view, redirect them to the proper URL.

You should also create a sitemap, which lists out all of the URLs for your website. You can then submit this sitemap to google using their [webmaster tool](https://www.google.com/webmasters/) if you have not already done so. This will inform their crawler of all the pages that they need to crawl without worrying on them missing some information.